# How can I get stack trace of a currently executing Task?

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace

I have a method that is called every time a new event to the application arrives. This method spins up a new task to process the event so we can return quickly. For example:

```
public void HandleEvent(Event e)
{
  Task.Run(() => 
  {
    // Do something with e
  }
}
```

Sometimes processing that event takes a really long time and I want to find out why. One way I am thinking of doing this is to keep track of all currently executing such tasks and create a monitoring thread that keeps an eye for any tasks that have taken longer than a certain amount of time. When that happens, have the monitor take a stack trace of that task's thread.

Is this possible?

I suppose that if it's impossible or too difficult to get a stack trace of a running thread that I could somehow trigger ProcDump externally, though that would be overkill and potentially grab a lot of data I don't need. (This is a server process so I expect that there will be hundreds if not thousands of processing threads).

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: You can just use a regular profiler to see where this operation is spending most of its time.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624188.aspx

Comment: Can you signal the task to throw an exception? If so, the exception will contain the stack trace.

Comment: The application is running on a production server that I can't touch. I can only see logs. Also, I don't necessarily want to cause the task to die with an exception (it could be in the middle of doing anything and it may not be broken). I just want to capture a snapshot of it.