# Get the stack trace from running Task

Tags: c#, .net, task, stack-trace

I want get the stack trace from a running task to know where is blocked.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task = Task.Run((Action)DoSomething);
        if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Timeout from the task {task.Id}.");
            Console.WriteLine(DisplayStackTrace(task));
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Being work");
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("End work");
    }

    static string DisplayStackTrace(Task task)
    {
        ?????
    }
}
```

Can you help me to get the StackTrace from a Task?

This is similar to [How can I get stack trace of a currently executing Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201352/how-can-i-get-stack-trace-of-a-currently-executing-task), but this question hasn't answer.

Comment: It's not similar. That question fires off a task that's never awaited. In any case, a task represents a promise that something will produce a value. It's not a thread nor a function so it doesn't have a call stack. It's no different thatn an `Action<T>` that hasn't been invoked. `DoSomething` is the thing that has a call stack.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? If you want to clean up the call stack of an asynchronous method check [Ben.Demystifier](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier).

Comment: I try diagnostic where (method) is blocked the task.

Comment: that's already available in Visual Studio's [Parallel Stacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-parallel-stacks-window?view=vs-2017) window (Debug> Windows> Parallel Stacks). The [concurrency visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2017) can show you a view of which task blocked which one across time.

Comment: The Parallel Stacks Window display nothing. But the Thread Window is good. Thank.

Comment: It's production bug. I can't reproduce in my developpement environement. I need add code to the production to diagnostique this problem.

Comment: You still can't get a call stack from a Task, it doesn't have one. *Threads* have call stacks. You'll find various questions that show how to solve your *actual* problem, how to find where each thread is stuck. For example, you can [debug a crash dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2017) of a managed application in Visual Studio and see where each thread was at the moment of the crash. You can create a crash dump  from a running application with tools like `procdump`

Comment: Other options are to [record IntelliTrace events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-intellitrace-stand-alone-collector?view=vs-2017) in production and then [replay the trace in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-saved-intellitrace-data?view=vs-2017). You can add Application Insights to your application and monitor its behaviour. You could use WinDbg in production to get the call stacks of all threads.

Comment: Multi-server web sites log operations using centralized logging infrastructure that may range from Application Insights or Azure Log Analytics to specialized services like Splunk to custom solution built on top of Elasticsearch.